# How to show the original image in galleria jquery library

Tags: jquery, image, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, galleria

I want images to display in their original size, not stretched. How? How can I disable that.

Anyone who knows the solution please help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**`max_scale_ratio`**

- type: `Number`
- default: `undefined`
- Sets the maximum scale ratio for images. F.ex, if you don't want Galleria to upscale any images, set this to `1`.
- `undefined` will allow any scaling of the images.